# Reset the FB Like Button

Tags: testing, facebook-like

How do I reset the Like button code on a page I am testing so it doesn't stay grey? I need to be able to click the Like button to test the implementation but I can't do this unless I can reset it. I tried deleting the FB post, but that doesn't work. I assume it's a cache issue at that point.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done, is clicked the small X that's usually somewhere on the Like button, which unlikes it, and resets it in that way.